# I am running webODM after customizing some code that uses opencv library, however after restarting the dockerfile I get an error

Tags: python, django, opencv, dockerfile

I am customizing the [WebODM](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/WebODM) and added my own plugin which includes opencv, matplotlib libraries. I am running the webODM as a docker file so after building the images to register the plugin I get:
`WARNING Failed to instantiate plugin diagnostic: No module named 'cv2'`

If I comment the `import cv2` I in-turn get No module named 'matplotlib'. But in the environment I am running the django app, I can safely import cv2 in the python shell without issues.

I suspect the issue is the dockerfile is sort of using some other python environment that causes it not to recognize cv2. How can I resolve this issue?